# Using newly created ID for another field name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app I have two fields - the default `id` and one called `friendly_id` which should consist of some random UPPERCASE letters and the `id`. For example

Where id = **354**, friendly_id might = **HDG354**

From my controller I call the method in my model like this:

```
@booking.save_and_send
```

where @booking is a new instance of a booking.

In my model I have:

```
def save_and_send
  if valid?
    self.friendly_id = 3.times.map { [*'A'..'Z'].sample }.join + self.id.to_s
    save!

    GuestMailer.booking_created(self).deliver
  end
end
```

but of course I can't use the ID if the instance hasn't been saved yet - would you recommend saving twice in the same method or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you swap the positions?

```
def save_and_send
  if valid?
    save!
    self.update_attributes(friendly_id: 3.times.map { [*'A'..'Z'].sample }.join + self.id.to_s)

    GuestMailer.booking_created(self).deliver
  end
end
```

A better way to achieve this might be to create an `after_create` callback.

Comment: You already know the answer buddy. Without save, there will be no id.

Comment: ha ha yeah I do - I misread you line as I didnt' see that you'd changed it to update_attributes - I thought you just re-used my line.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in an `after_create` callback:

```
after_create do |booking|
  booking.update_attributes(friendly_id: 3.times.map { [*'A'..'Z'].sample }.join + booking.id.to_s)
  GuestMailer.booking_created(booking).deliver
end
```

Comment: yes didn't think about a callback - will test later on today. thanks for this